# Can't plot with minimum and maximum latitude and longitude in folium

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to plot a map in folium and i only wanted to show the location with this coordinates coordinates latitude 5° to 30° and longitude 60° to 95°

```
    import folium
    
    
    mapLayer = folium.Map(min_lat=5, max_lat=30, min_lon=60, max_lon=95)
    mapLayer.save("./folium_map/data/map.html")
```

The output is not what i expected can anyone tell me what's going wrong here

The ploted map,
[image: plot after running the code]

Comment: The basic specification is the center point of the map. You can also set the maximum and minimum latitude and longitude to fix the zoom and movement range.

Comment: @r-beginners yo saying is i need to have the location parameter?

Comment: Yes, it is. Try this and see. `mapLayer = folium.Map(location=[17.5,75.5], min_lat=5, max_lat=30, min_lon=60, max_lon=95)`